OneDrive fails to sync when offline for a long time (weeks)
I have a Microsoft 365 subscription which comes with 1 TB Onedrive storage. I am using it in multiple computers regularly.
The syncing of files is smooth enough when I am logging in the computers regularly. However I am facing major problems with syncing when the system is offline for a few weeks. There is no syncing of files and the Onedrive interface in system tray shows syncing is complete and all files are up to date even when they are not.
The solution is to reset onedrive using Onedrive.exe /reset command in Run. But this forces download of all the files from cloud to local storage which is slow and takes a lot of time. The selective sync option via 'choose folders' settings is lost and I am able to update it only after dowloading of all the files is complete.
Several times I have failed to get any work done while travelling because my laptop onedrive fails to sync as it was offline for a few weeks.
I am facing this issue in both windows 10 and 11.
Is there a more elegant and simple fix for this ?
